# Keep getting error trying to knit R Markdown

Tags: r

I keep getting this when trying to save my knit..... Error: `clean_names()` requires that either names or dimnames be non-null. Execution halted

these are the clean names I use

```r
df<- clean_names(df)
df<-remove_empty(df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to SO, sarah lewerenz! We can't help: we don't know the data (`df`), the libraries/packages, any relevant preceding code, and how your rmarkdown file is constructed/executed. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.